# WebStorm 2016.2 live edit for a node.js app not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webstorm

I'm working on a `node.js` and `angular.js` app with `WebStorm 2016.2` but the live edit function doesn't work, so I have to restart the server for each change on the `node.js` side. (Changes in `angular`are immediately seen in the browser without server restart.)

I checked and the `Live Edit` plugin is installed. I tried both in `run` and `debug` modes. What am I missing?

Comment: What is your Node.js version? Is your server-side code written in pure javascript, or do you pre-compile it in some way? also, please make sure that 'Update' in Preferences/Build, Execution, Deployment/Debugger/Live Edit is set to 'Auto in (ms)' and 'Restart if hotswap fails' is enabled.

Comment: I'm using version 4.4.7 and it's pure javascript.

Comment: @lena I also enabled the Auto option and the Restart if hotswap fails but I still need to restart the server for my changes to catch.

Comment: works for me. please create a support ticket